# How can I disable FilledTextField component?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

How can I disable FilledTextField component like a Button or something else? Are there some modifier or some wrapper to switch disable/enable state of UI components in Android Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `1.0.0-beta01` you can use:

```
TextField(
    enabled = false,
    ...
)
```